# Axios POST 404 not found

Tags: reactjs, email, axios

I want send email with form in react and to send the body to node i use axios.post this is my code:

```
handleSubmit = async e => {
e.preventDefault();

const { name, number, email, message } = this.state;

await axios.post("/send", { name, number, email, message });

console.log(this.state);
};
```

and the error messsage is:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/send 404 (Not Found)
createError.js:17 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
```

i don't know why

Comment: `"/send"` is pointing to your frontend server, not the backend server

Comment: What i have to do

Comment: You need to either post to the full URL for your backend instead of a relative path, or pass a `baseURL` property in a config object (third argument to `.post()`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set your backend server baseUrl you can do it like this

```
 await axios.post("baseUrl/send", { name, number, email, message });
```

or you can create instance of axios and set your base url and use your instance to send request

```
const instance = axios.create({
   baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/',
   timeout: 1000,
   headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'}
});
```

then use this instance to send requests